# How to implement multiple tbody elements into jquery tablesaw plugin?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, responsive

It seems like, using more than one tbody element inside table breaks tablesaw plugin, responsiveness is working only on last tbody, or am I missing something.

I'm using latest plugin and swipe mode.

Plugin here https://github.com/filamentgroup/tablesaw

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('table.search')
    .addClass('tablesaw tablesaw-stack')
    .attr({
        "data-tablesaw-mode": "stack"
    });

$('table.search tr td:first-child, table.search tr td:nth-child(3)')
    .attr({ 'data-tablesaw-priority': 'persist' })
    .addClass("title");

$('table.dataList')
    .addClass("tablesaw tablesaw-swipe")
    .attr({
        "data-tablesaw-mode": "swipe"
    });

$('table.dataList tr th')
    .attr({
        'scope': 'col'
    })


$('table.dataList tr th:first-child')
    .attr({ 'data-tablesaw-priority': 'persist' })
    .addClass("title");

$('table.dataList tr td:first-child').addClass('title');

$( document ).trigger( "enhance.tablesaw" );
});
```

[image]

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: what is the role of tbody?

Comment: edited, added jquery and html, since i have multiple tables inside multiple pages, i add classes dynamically